# Method not found: 'MyProject.MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes'

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, mono

I build a simple ASP.NET MVC 2 project with MonoDevelop, it is ok when it run at debug server of MonoDevelop.

Then I generate virtual host conf file at http://go-mono.com/config-mod-mono/Default.aspx and try to run at apache, it throw exception:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'MyProject.MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes'

How should I fix this problem?
(mono version: 2.10.8, apache version: 2.2.23, mod_mono version: 2.10)

Comment: I have the exact same error, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You are using mod-mono-server2 which is for asp.net 2.0, but you need support for asp.net 4.0

Change your host conf file to use mod-mono-server4

I also needed to install it which on ubuntu required the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install mono-apache-server4
```